# Obfuscating data for other roles in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, security, encryption, obfuscation

To comply with privacy guidelines, I want to binary obfuscate the contents of certain columns to other roles, including the administrative role/developers.
A table could look like this:

```
create table customer (
    id serial primary key,
    role text not null default session_user,
    name text not null,
    address text not null,
    phone bigint default null
);

create policy customer_policy on customer
    for all to public using (role = session_user);
```

In this example, the column contents such as name, address and phone should not be visible to other roles.
the policy only guarantees that roles of other database users cannot see the records, but the administrator with higher privileges, for example, can still see the data.

my idea is that a password is stored in another table that is created and changed by the respective role. the relevant columns are then encrypted and decrypted using this password.

How could this be implemented or does PostgreSQL already offer solutions for this?